# Free tool or library to convert Tiff files to pdf in .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net, pdf, tiff

Does any one know of a free tool or library to convert multi page tiffs to pdf in Asp.Net 1.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about [PDFSharp](http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/), or  [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)?  I usually search sf.net first when looking for a free library.

Answer (score 2):

[LibTiff.Net library](https://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) and [tiff2pdf utility](https://github.com/BitMiracle/libtiff.net/tree/master/Tiff2Pdf) (comes in source code with the library) can be used to convert TIFF images to PDF documents in .NET

The library and the utility use .NET 2.0 but you probably will be able to build .NET 1.1 version without modifications. The library and utility are free and open source and their code doesn't use generics and other things absent from .NET 1.1.

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of the library.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

```
convert screenshot.tiff screenshot.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Persist software's ASPPDFlib.dll might be of your help. http://www.asppdf.com/download.html

Comment: It's not free. Neither are many other great products.

Answer (score 0):

Look into PDF Creator http://www.pdfforge.org/products/pdfcreator

I know you can script it, but I don't know if you can do anything with it via ASP.NET. Either way it couldn't hurt to look.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this in asp.net before (actually JPG to PDF but close enough...)
I use ImageMagick and shell out to it. I know its not native c# code, but its free and it works brilliantly.
Just run a command line like this:

cmd /c convert "c:\blah\original.tiff" "c:\blah\destination.pdf"

The reason i use the 'cmd /c' is that without it, i have problems with System.Diagnostics.Process.Start messing up the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use PdfFoucs dll for converting PDF to Image, Word, Text format in 4 lines of code. No need to install any exe for that.

Code for converting in MultiTiff Image:

```
SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();
f.OpenPdf(FilePath);

if (f.PageCount > 0)
{
    f.ToMultipageTiff(FilePath);
}
```

Code for converting in Tiff Image based on homany pages are there in PDF:

```
SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();
f.OpenPdf(FilePath);

if (f.PageCount > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < f.PageCount; i++)
    {
       f.ImageOptions.Dpi = 200;
       System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp1 = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)f.ToDrawingImage(i + 1);
       bmp1.Save(Server.MapPath("~/FileUpload/") + filename + "_" + (i + 1) + ".tiff");
     }
}
```

Code for converting in Worrd:

```
SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();
f.OpenPdf(FilePath);

if (f.PageCount > 0)
{
    f.ToWord(FilePath);
}
```

Only you need to add the DLL in your application. Trial version as well as license versions are available on sautinsoft site